# What is the shortest distance from the ellipse $x^2+\frac{y^2}{4} =1$ and the point (2,2).

Tags: multivariable-calculus, projection

What is the shortest distance from the ellipse $x^2+\frac{y^2}{4} =1$ and the point (2,2).

I know that this is the projection of (2,2) onto the ellipse. How do I go about finding the shortest distance between this point and the curve?

Comment: -1. No effort to try to solve the problem yourself. No effort to check if there is already a solution on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Define point $P(2,2)$.  The tangents to the curve $$x^2+\frac14y^2=1$$ will have a slope of $m=-\dfrac{4x}{y}$ or $-\dfrac{2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.  At some $x$ value, the point of tangency will be $Q(x,2\sqrt{1-x^2})$.  We want $m$ and $PQ$ to be perpendicular, and thus their values will be of negative reciprocal.

As such, we have $$\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2x}=\frac{2\sqrt{1-x^2}-2}{x-2}\implies x\approx0.69661$$

(use a numerical method).

Now that you have your point $Q$, you can find the length of $PQ$.

Comment: Concerning your last equation, let $\sin \left(2 \tan ^{-1}(u)\right)$ to end with $u^4+7 u^3+u-1=0$ which can be solved with messy radicals. Otherwise, Householde method starting at $x_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$  leads to an approximate $x=\frac{3 \left(116636+91089 \sqrt{2}\right)}{1021156}\approx 0.72111$ while the exact solution is ... the same. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can think about this as a constrained optimization problem.  You want to minimize the function $f(x,y) = (x-2)^2 + (y-2)^2$ [the square of the distance from $(x,y)$ to $(2,2)$], subject to the constraint that $x^2+y^2/4=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that the gradients of level curves are perpendicular to them then seek for $(x,y)$ such that
$$[2x,\frac{1}{2}y]=\lambda[2(x-2),2(y-2)].$$
This models how the normal to the ellipse is aligned to the normal of a circle centered at $(2,2)$.

The next plot may help you to think towards the solution

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$ 
[image]